# Core Data - How to force NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType context save in serial?

Tags: iphone, core-data, concurrency

I was excited about the newly supported concurrent functions of CoreData since iOS 5.

A private queue is maintained and all save or fetch requests can be done via that queue.

However, can I set up `the private queue` for CoreData so that **it executes request one by one**?

My app is downloading news items from a number of feeds. Each time after downloading and parsing from one feed are finished, I just save the feed's items into CoreData via the private queue.

However, since I am downloading and parsing from multiple feeds simultaneously, I always have multiple groups of items, i.e., `multiple save requests`, for the CoreData.

Now the situation is that I guess CoreData just have a number of threads and each one is saving a group of items into the db. My UI got stuck in the mean time.

Do you think I can control the private queue so that no matter how many simultaneous save requests are, they will be done one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data is (probably) only using one serial queue or thread since its serial. I recently converted my app from using a serial queue I had created (app was 4.3) to use this new option in iOS 5. In all cases when you 'performBlock' the method is handled in a serial fashion. Also, you can now call '[moc performBlocK:...]' from any queue as that call is thread safe!

I believe what you want to do is have your background threads, which are most likely adding options, to use 'performBlock:' (without the wait). The block you provide is then queued and processed in a FIFO fashion. Later on, if your table wants to get objects, it can issue a 'performBlockAndWait:', or optionally your code can ask for the latest objects using performBlock, and at the end of the supplied block message back to your app the set of objects you need.

Also, I only ever save often in development builds, to verify validity. Once you are pretty sure things are working OK, you can then just perform a background save once all the data is downloaded.

EIDT: To reiterate - if you are downloading and also using images or other data while loading a viewController, and lots of things are going on, this is the WORST time to do a save. Use a timer or dispatch_after, and many seconds after everything seems stable THEN do the save.

Comment: The problem I have is that the saving of CoreData let my app freezes. It runs of course smoothly in simulator, but on iPhone, it just freezes my UI (not totally freezes, but lots of lag on UI)

Comment: Don't do it with performBlockAndWait - use performBlock, and when the save succeeds or fails message your main controller back on the main thread with the result. I add hundreds of images to my context along with other stuff, do the save asynchronously when its done, not a twitch of delay in the UI.

Comment: Yes, I used performBlock for sure. I tried to save 50 groups of items into coredata, my UI almost can't move.

Comment: I cannot know all your app. What I do know is that in my app, I download a huge numbers of images, add them to a Core Data SQLite backed repository, and its all working well. That said, I only save thumbnails and small images in the repository, for large megabyte images I write to the fileSystem then save the URL in Core Data.